# Java DateTime, Unreachable catch block for ParseException

Tags: java, datetime, java-8

This is the method to parse the date object into a particular pattern. But it is giving error for the catch block saying it is unreachable and I can either remove the catch block or throw the exception directly. The reason I wanted catch block is to have visibility should there occur any error.

```
public static Date parseDate(Date a, String someFormat) {
    Date parsedDate = null;
    DateTimeFormatter dateFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(someFormat);
    try {
        Instant instant = a.toInstant();

        LocalDate localDate =LocalDate.parse(dateFormat.format(instant), dateFormat);
        parsedDate = Date.from(localDate.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        logger.error(ExceptionUtils.getRootCauseMessage(e), e);
    }
    return parsedDate;
}
```

Comment: `ParseException` is a checked exception, it is not thrown from any of the statement inside your try block, try `Exception` instead `ParseException`

Comment: What part of the code is supposed to throw ParseException and what package is that class comming from? There is a java.text.ParseException but that exception is obviously not thrown in the above case. LocalDate.parse just throws DateTimeParseException, which is a RuntimeException anyway.

Comment: If the compiler says the catch block is unreachable, you can be very sure it will never be invoked, meaning there will never be an exception thrown and there is nothing to give visibility to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only checked exception that your `try` block throws is not a `ParseException`, which is what a `SimpleDateFormat` would throw, but a `DateTimeParseException`, which is what [`LocalDate.parse`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter-) throws, and a [`DateTimeParseException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeParseException.html) is not a `ParseException`.

The compiler sees the `catch` block as unreachable because the `ParseException` is never thrown from the `try` block.

Just catch `DateTimeParseException` instead.

```
} catch (DateTimeParseException e) {
```

Note that because it's a `RuntimeException`, it's not absolutely necessary to catch it at all.  But since you are already attempting to have "visibility", which is a good thing, and you're already attempting to catch an exception, just catch the correct exception type.